# Javascript and HTML - Adding a dropdown menu, what am I doing wrong here?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I just copied the dropdown menu from W3Schools and changed their class names/id's so I can use it in my code.

I have two things:

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. What does the for-loop, not for-in, do? What is the purpose of incrementing by one?

HTML:

```
<body>
    <nav class = "header">
        <div id = "logo"> <a href = "ee"/> </a> </div>
        <ul>
            <li class = "nav_li" id= "cata_li" onclick = "myFunction()">  
            <a class ="nav_a" href="ee"> Find <br/> Poop</a> 
                <ul class = "dropdown_menu">
                    <li> <a href = "#"> Horse poop </a> </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
```

JavaScript:

```
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("cata_li").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches(".nav_li")) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown_menu");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

CSS (I am sure nothing is wrong here, my CSS still looks the same):

```
 .header > ul{
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 250px;
}

.header> ul > li{
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    vertical-align: top; 
}

.dropdown_menu{
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    z-index: 40;
    top:50px;
    left:0;
    background-color: #222;
    width: 300px;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 issues here, In your `nav_a` is an anchor element whose default action is to navigate to the href value, here you need to prevent it.

Also the `matches` function will just check for the current element, you need to check whether the click has happened inside a `nav_li` element so use [.closest()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) instead

```js
function myFunction(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  document.querySelector("#cata_li .dropdown_menu").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.closest(".nav_li")) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown_menu");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.header > ul {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 250px;
}
.header> ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.dropdown_menu {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  z-index: 40;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #222;
  width: 300px;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 10px;
}
.dropdown_menu.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav class="header">
  <div id="logo">
    <a href="ee"></a>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li class="nav_li" id="cata_li" onclick="myFunction(event)">
      <a class="nav_a" href="ee"> Find <br/> Poop</a>
      <ul class="dropdown_menu">
        <li> <a href="#"> Horse poop </a> 
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: hank you so much! but would you mind telling me waht the for loop is for ? I dont get it's purpose